# Sorting algorithm with Cuda. Inside or outside kernels?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, cuda

I have a matrix of size 50000x100 and I need to sort each row using Cuda in C++. My architecture is a K80 NVidia card.

Since the number of columns is small, I am currently running the sorting algorithm inside a kernel. I am using a modified bubble algorithm that runs on all lines of the matrix.

I am wondering if there is an more efficient way to proceed. I tried to use thrust::sort inside my kernel but it is much slower. I also tried a merge sort algorithm but the recursive part of the algorithm didn't work inside my kernel.

==edit==

here is my kernel:

```
__global__ void computeQuantilesKernel(float *matIn, int nRows, int nCols, int nQuantiles, float *outsideValues, float *quantilesAve, int param2)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    float values[100];//big enough for 100 columns
    int keys[100];
    int nQuant[100];//big enough for 100 quantiles (percentiles)
    float thisQuantile[100];
    int quant;

    if (idx >= nRows) return;

    //read matIn from global memory
    for (int i = 0; i < nCols; i++)
    {
        values[i] = matIn[idx * nCols + i + param2 * nCols * nRows];
        keys[i] = i;
    }

    //bubble Sort:
    int i, j;
    int temp;
    float tempVal;

    for (i = 0; i < nCols - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < nCols - i - 1; j++)
        {
            if (values[j + 1] < values[j])      // ascending order simply changes to <
            {
                tempVal = values[j];             // swap elements
                temp = keys[j];             // swap elements
                values[j] = values[j + 1];
                keys[j] = keys[j + 1];
                values[j + 1] = tempVal;
                keys[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    //end of bubble sort

    //reset nQuant and thisQuantile
    for (int iQuant = 0; iQuant < nQuantiles; iQuant++)
    {
        nQuant[iQuant] = 0;
        thisQuantile[iQuant] = 0;
    }

    //Compute sum of outsideValues for each quantile
    for (int i = 0; i < nCols; i++)
    {
        quant = (int)(((float)i + 0.5) / ((float)nCols / (float)nQuantiles));//quantile like Matlab
        nQuant[quant]++;
        thisQuantile[quant] += outsideValues[idx * nCols + keys[i]];
    }

    //Divide by the size of each quantile to get averages
    for (int iQuant = 0; iQuant < nQuantiles; iQuant++)
    {
        quantilesAve[idx + nRows * iQuant + param2 * nQuantiles * nRows] = thisQuantile[iQuant] / (float)nQuant[iQuant];
    }
}
```

Comment: please post a [mcve] as a baseline that solutions can be compared against

Comment: try a [vectorized sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150098/how-to-use-thrust-to-sort-the-rows-of-a-matrix).  I think your question could arguably be considered a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @Robert, thank you very much for the link. I am sorry I missed it before posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code as it stands uses a single thread to handle each of your rows separately. As a result you are starving for quick scratch memory (registers, L1 cache, shared memory). You are allocating at least 1600 bytes per each thread - that is a lot! You want to stay at around 128 bytes per thread (32 registers of 32 bits each). Secondly, you are using local arrays addressable at run-time -- those arrays will be spilled into local memory, trash your L1 cache and end up in global memory again (1600B x 32 threads gives 51KB, which is already at or above the limits of shmem/L1).

For that reason I would suggest handling a single row per block of 64 or 128 threads instead, and keep the row you sort in shared memory. Bubble sort is actually very easy to implement in parallel:

```
__shared__ float values[nCols];
... load the data ...
__syncthreads();
for (int i = 0; i < nCols/2; i++)
{
    int j = threadIdx.x;
    if (j % 2 == 0 && j<nCols-1)
        if (values[j+1] < values[j])
            swap(values[j+1], values[j]);
    __syncthreads();
    if (j % 2 == 1 && j<nCols-1)
        if (values[j+1] < values[j])
            swap(values[j+1], values[j]);
    __syncthreads();
}
```

Notice how your inner `for j = ...` loop is replaced by `threadIdx`, but the core idea of the algorithm stays the same. In each iteration I perform bubble swap first only on even pairs and then only on odd pairs to avoid parallel conflicts.

I assume that `nCols` is lower than the dimension of your block, which for 100 elements is easily achievable.

There are many ways that the above code can be improved further, for example

- Cut the thread count in half and assume `j=threadIdx.x*2` for the first half of the loop, and `j=threadIdx.x*2+1` for the second half. This way no thread stays idle.
- Use only 32 threads, each handling two values of `j` sequentially. This way your problem will fit a single warp, allowing you to drop `__syncthreads()` altogether. With 32 threads, you might be able to use warp shuffle intrinsics.
- Experiment with `#pragma unroll`, although the amount of produce code may be unfeasible. Profiling will help.

Also consider experimenting with hardcoded merge sort instead of bubble sort. If my memory serves me right, when I implemented a warp-sized bubble sort and merge-sort with all loops unrolled, merge sort performed almost twice as fast as bubble sort. Note, it was several years ago, on the first generation of CUDA-capable cards.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. I will try to implement it tomorrow and see if I understand everything you wrote.

Comment: After trying your suggestions, I rewrote my kernel to handle a single row per blocks of 32 threads in which I sequentially run 4 columns.
I changed my mind with the hard coded sorting algorithm and went for CUB's blockRadixSort.
Altogether, I could lower the computing time by 60%. 
Once again, @CygnusX1, thank you very much. You made me learn a few things that will be very helpful in the future.