# Calling thrust function inside a CUDA Kernel __global___

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, thrust

I've read about that the dynamic parallelism is supported in the newer version of CUDA, and I can call thrust functions like `thrush::exclusive_scan` inside a kernel function with `thrust::device` parameter.

```cpp
__global__ void kernel(int* inarray, int n, int *result) {
  extern __shared__ int s[];
  int t = threadIdx.x;

  s[t] = inarray[t];
  __syncthreads();

  thrust::exclusive_scan(thrust::device, s, n, result);
  __syncthreads();
}

int main() {
  // prep work

  kernel<<<1, n, n * sizeof(int)>>>(inarray, n, result);
}
```

The thing I got confused is:

1. When calling thrust function inside a kernel, does each thread call the function once and they all do a dynamic parallelism on the data?
2. If they do, I only need one thread to call `thrust` so I can just do a `if` to `threadIdx`; if not, how do threads in a block communicate with each other that the call to thrust has been done and they should just ignore it(this seems a little imaginary since there wouldn't be a systematical way to ensure from user's code). To summerize, what's exactly happening when I call thrust functions with `thrust::device` parameter inside a kernel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Every thread in your kernel that executes the thrust algorithm will execute a separate copy of your algorithm.  The threads in your kernel do not cooperate on a single algorithm call.
2. If you have met all the requirements (HW/SW and compilation settings) for a CUDA dynamic parallelism (CDP) call, then each thread that encounters the thrust algorithm call will launch a CDP child kernel to perform the thrust algorithm  (in that case, the threads in the CDP child kernel **do** cooperate).  If not, each thread that encounters the thrust algorithm call will perform it as if you had specified `thrust::seq` instead of `thrust::device`.
3. If you prefer to avoid the CDP activity in an otherwise CDP-capable environment, you can specify `thrust::seq` instead.
4. If you intend, for example, that only a single copy of your thrust algorithm be executed, it will be necessary in your kernel code to ensure that only one thread calls it, for example:

   ```
   if (!threadIdx.x) thrust::exclusive_scan(...
   ```

   or similar.
5. Questions around synchronization before/after the call are no different from ordinary CUDA code.  If you need all threads in the block to wait for the thrust algorithm to complete, use e.g. `__syncthreads()`, (and `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` in the CDP case).

The information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150098/how-to-use-thrust-to-sort-the-rows-of-a-matrix/28254765#28254765) may possibly be of interest as well.